# How to get the last directory from a ftp url C#

Tags: c#, url, ftp, directory

Is there a class or method in .NET 3.5 to get the last directory from a ftp Url?

I have in a string variable the ftp url like this and in this case I want to retrieve Directory2

```
ftp://user:password@server:port/Directory1/Directory2
```

In this case the root

```
ftp://user:password@server:port/
```

I was trying to find something like Path.GetDirectoryName(string) but I can't find.

I found that there is a way with Uri class and Segments.

The longest will be split by "/" and verify that is not the "/" from ftp://

There is another way already provided in .NET?

Thanks.

Comment: Nope. You need to keep track of which directory you transverse.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
string ftp = "ftp://user:password@server:port/Directory1/Directory2";
string lastDir= ftp.Substring(ftp.LastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

lastDir will store the name of last dir

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I only want to know what will happen if the ftp url change to this "ftp : // user:password@server:port". So, I will get "user:password@server:port"

Answer (score 2):

First:

```
string path = "ftp://user:password@server:port/Directory1/Directory2";
```

And then you can try with this:

```
string[] table = Path.GetDirectoryName(path).Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
```

And select last element of the table.

Ofc if you don't want the default separator you may define it in different way:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(path).Split(new[] {"cool separator"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```